# Add custom colors in Datatable Excel export

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want dynamic color in datatable export. I have a handle in view for different colors as per column value. How can I achieve it for datatable export? It's taking only inbuilt color as they provided as per [this link](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5) but I want to add dark yellow/green I'm not able to add it in the export.

I tried to add custom color using

```
$(this).attr('background-color', '#66FF33'); 

// and also
$(this).css('background', '#66FF33');
```

Although it didn't work.

```js
var table = $('#OperationDataTable').DataTable({
  "stripeClasses": ['odd-row', 'even-row'],
  "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 100, 150],
  "pageLength": 50,
  "aaSorting": [],
  responsive: true,
  fixedHeader: false,
  dom: 'lfBrtip',
  buttons: [{
    // 'excel'
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    customize: function(xlsx) {
      var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
      $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '42');
      $('row c[r^="D"]', sheet).each(function() {
        if ($('is t', this).text() == "Negative NFE") {
          $(this).attr('s', '20');
          //$(this).attr( 'background-color', '#66FF33' );
        } else if ($('is t', this).text() == "Online Done") {

        } else {
          $(this).attr('s', '34');
        }
      });
    }
  }]
});
```

or its should be export as showing in datatable view(means with html/css)

Comment: You will need to create a custom style that has the font, border and background color defined. Getting started: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/34288/how-can-i-give-styles-in-data-table-excel-export

Comment: @lofihelsinki,, i created custome css by using $(this).attr('background-color', '#66FF33'); 

// and also
$(this).css('background', '#66FF33');
as mention above but its not working

Comment: As mentioned in the linked document, you **can't use CSS** styling the excel. You need to define XLSX-styles that is a tad more compliacated-

Comment: so is this only solution?? how can i use in above code?

Comment: Seems so. I don't know the details but you can look here how XLSX styles are declared: https://github.com/DataTables/Buttons/blob/35c566b32fb7716539a1e63ebf511638d3eb3596/js/buttons.html5.js#L676

Comment: can u tell simple method to export table as its showing in datatable view?

Comment: Use PDF export.